# User trustable random number generation

Tags: random, hash

I have a 8-character string based on a timestamp (DDhhmmss) which I plan to push through a hashing routine in order to get a pseudo-random series of bits.

How does SHA1 compare to other hashing algorithms (such as MD5) with regards the generation of hashes that are roughly evenly distributed across the different combinations of 8 numbers?

(I realise it's a strange question, but I'm looking for algorithms that when the user gives a seed value can generate a series of bits that can be confirmed later by the user to be genuinely pseudo-random and not unpredictably-random - hence using hashing algorithms - and particularly ones that are hosted on the internet somewhere too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) still has some merits as a hash function, even though it is not suitable for cryptographic applications anymore. It is simple, fast and available almost everywhere in multiple implementations (internal/external libraries, operating system, external programs) so that you can not only use it without fuss but also easily verify proper operation against some alternative implementation. Think of it as a big brother of CRC32.

[SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) has no such merits, and it has been eclipsed in every regard by newer generations of standard hashes (SHA-256 as an incarnation of [SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2); [SHA-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3)). Not to mention that SHA-0 is occasionally mislabelled as SHA-1, which causes no end of fun for all concerned.

That said it should be virtually impossible to detect bias in any of those hashes, without massive computing power and advanced cryptanalytic techniques (e.g. differential cryptanalysis). For practical reasons and flexibility I'd stick with MD5.

Note: you can generate a secret (unguessable) sequence by adding a pseudo-random salt to your timestamp, storing it in a database or log, and publishing a one-way function of it (e.g. its hash). Any sequence can then later by verified by producing the salt and showing that its hash matches the published hash; salt and time stamp together then produce the original sequence. If you are running games then the seed/salt can be published as soon as the game is over.

Since the word 'trust' comes into play here I'd consider SHA-256 instead of MD5 if large communities of gamers are involved, and/or run MD5 iteratively in the way of [key derivation functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) when computing the hash of the salt that gets published. The object is to make it impractical to mount a brute-force attack against the published hash to get the secret seed/salt.

Also, only SHA-256 has enough internal state to generate all possible hands for a 52-card deck. Naked MD5 and SHA-1 are too small, but there are easy ways around that (just use more state). Your time stamp is the biggest problem here, has it has far fewer possible states than the ~2^226 required for dealing a fair hand of poker, and the salt that you add has to pick up the slack. E.g. draw 256 bits from /dev/urandom. Of course, that makes the time stamp sort of redundant in this protocol...

An alternative would be to use a bigger 'id', like the actual text for a game challenge or whatever happens to be handy. Salting is still required to prevent cheating, though.

P.S.: the protocol would be simplest if you could draw entropy from /dev/urandom or something equivalent, use it to seed your generator, and publish a strong one-way function of it in base-64 or base-96 as the 'game id'. I.e. ditch the time stamp. The key derivation function would be run sort of backwards here but the security ramifications are exactly the same.